# Kotlin null-safety for class properties

Tags: null, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

How can I avoid using `!!` for optional properties of class

```
class PostDetailsActivity {

    private var post: Post? = null

    fun test() {
        if (post != null) {
            postDetailsTitle.text = post.title    // Error I have to still force using post!!.title
            postDetailsTitle.author = post.author

            Glide.with(this).load(post.featuredImage).into(postDetailsImage)

        } else {
            postDetailsTitle.text = "No title"
            postDetailsTitle.author = "Unknown author"

            Toast.makeText(this, resources.getText(R.string.post_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Should I create a local variable? I think using `!!` is not a good practice

Comment: Android Studio gives you the reason as _"'post' is a mutable property that could've been changed by this time"_. One possible alternative, depending on how you intend to use `title`, would be `post?.apply { title }`

Comment: what if I need the alternative condition like `else` ?

Comment: Could you please post a complete example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use apply:

```
fun test() {
    post.apply {
        if (this != null) {
            postDetailsTitle.text = title
        } else {
            postDetailsTitle.text = "No title"
        }
    }
}
```

or with:

```
fun test() {
    with(post) {
        if (this != null) {
            postDetailsTitle.text = title
        } else {
            postDetailsTitle.text = "No title"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems the most straight-forward solution for a single property. `let` could also be used. See also [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-null-check-for-multiple-nullable-vars/1946/13?u=mfulton26) for some alternatives which are especially useful when you have multiple properties.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
if (post != null) {
    postDetailsTitle.text = post.title    // Error I have to still force using post!!.title
} else {
    postDetailsTitle.text = "No title"
}
```

Could be replaced with:

```
postDetailsTitle.text = post?.title ?: "No title"
```

> If the expression to the left of ?: is not null, the elvis operator returns it, otherwise it returns the expression to the right.

Comment: I simplified a little bit all code I have a few other properties

Comment: Well, it would still be one line per property. `postDetailsTitle.propertyX = post?.propertyX ?: defaultX`

Comment: I don't want to copy full class, I added a few lines more

Comment: Ok, you've added some new things that weren't apparent from the start. I suppose you could create a local `val`/`var` and use that instead of `post`. Or you could wrap the whole if-else in `apply` like JB Nizet suggested.